# How to update each value with one query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a data as below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "exist": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "exist": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "exist": false
  }
]
```

When I findOneAndUpdate({_id:2}),{exist:true}), I hope that exist of 'id:1' is changed to false automatically in one query using aggregate or etc.
could you recommend some idea for it? Thank you so much for reading my question.

Comment: the array you have posted is your collection, not a subdocument?

Comment: @Yahya This is different Document each other

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting $set in your command.

`findOneAndUpdate( { id: 1 }, { $set: { exist: true } } )`

Comment: If I use your method,is exist of id 1  changed to false automaticall?

Comment: @DDDD yes it would.