# How to update each document with one query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a data as below.

```
// first document
  {
    "id": 1,
    "exist": true
  }
// second document
  {
    "id": 2,
    "exist": false
  }
// third document
  {
    "id": 3,
    "exist": false
  }
```

When I findOneAndUpdate({_id:2}),{exist:true}), I hope that exist of 'id:1' is changed to false automatically in one query using aggregate or etc.
could you recommend some idea for it? Thank you so much for reading my question.

Comment: Please avoid spam questions. You already asked it few hrs ago  [How to update each value with one query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391474/how-to-update-each-value-with-one-query-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what do you want to update in your collection but to update many document use `updateMany` :

```
db.collection.updateMany(
      { violations: { $gt: 1 } }, // the filter to select the wanted document
      { $set: { "exist" : true } } // the change to apply to the field
   );
```